# Disabling documentation for properties

Tags: stylecop

Is there any way to configure StyleCop to ignore documentation for properties? I would like to keep the rule only for methods, constructors and classes. I know we are able to disable fields with "Include Fields" option.

Answer (score 0):

The rules SA1609 and SA1610 cover the documentation for Properties and can be disabled.

This is for public and protected properties.

Comment: I know this answer is old but is wrong.. The rules SA1609 and SA1610 not remove the documentation on properties, these rules are about the "value" tag in the documentation.